# Is kernel density estimation sub-gaussian?

Tags: high-dimensional, probability-inequalities

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be i.i.d. samples drawn from a pdf $f(x)$ on the real line. The kernel density estimator is defined as follows,

$$\hat{f_n}(x) = \frac{1}{nh}\sum_1^n K(\frac{x-X_k}{h})$$

where $K:\mathbb{R}\to [0, \infty)$ satisfying $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}K(x) = 1$ and $h>0$.

How to prove that $\Vert \hat{f_n}(x) - f \Vert_1$ is sub-Gaussian w.r.t. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ i.e.

$$\mathbb{P}(|\Vert \hat{f_n}(x) - f \Vert_1 - \mathbb{E}(\Vert \hat{f_n}(x) - f \Vert_1)|\geq t) \leq 2e^{-\frac{nt^2}{2}}$$

where

$$\Vert \hat{f_n}(x) - f \Vert_1:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\hat{f_n}(x)-f(x)|dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(X_1, ..., X_n) = \Vert \hat{f_n} - f \Vert_1$, then
$$
|g(X_1, ..., X_k, ..., X_n) - g(X_1, ..., X'_k, ..., X_n)| = |\Vert\hat{f_n} - f \Vert_1 - \Vert\hat{f'_n} - f \Vert_1| \\
\leq \Vert\hat{f_n} - \hat{f'_n} \Vert_1 \qquad \text{(Triangle Inequality)}\\
=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{nh}|K(\frac{x-X_k}{h})-K(\frac{x-X'_k}{h})|dx\\
\leq \frac{2}{nh}\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(\frac{x-X_k}{h})dx\\
= \frac{2}{n}. \qquad \text{(Chain Rule)}
$$
Thus $g$ satisfies bounded difference inequality.
$$\mathbb{P}(|\Vert\hat{f_n} - f \Vert_1 - \mathbb{E}\Vert\hat{f_n} - f \Vert_1|) \leq 2\exp (\frac{2t^2}{\frac{4n}{n^2}}) = 2e^{-\frac{nt^2}{2}}$$